# STL generic algorithms - implicit conversion of the ranges element type to the predicates parameter type

Tags: c++, stl, implicit-conversion

Say I want to remove all punctuation characters within a `std::string` using the erase-remove idiom.

However, let `str` be of type `std::string`, this call won't compile

```
str.erase( std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ispunct), str.end() );
```

Now I guess, strictly speaking the `std::ispunct` callables parameter type is `int` and therefore doesn't match the ranges element type `char`.
However, as a `char` is a numeric type it should be convertible to `int`. I'm working with Lippman's C++ Primer book which states

> The algorithms that take predicates call the predicate on the elements in the input range. [...] it must be possible to convert the element type to the parameter type in the input range.

which imo is given in the above statement.
Also `std::ispunct` returns an `int`, and thus should be usable as a condition.

So why does the compiler complain `no matching function for call to 'remove_if'`?
(`clang++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cc`)

A fix would be to use a lambda

```
str.erase( std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
              [] ( unsigned char ch ) { return std::ispunct(ch); }),
            str.end() );
```

still it suprised me that a lambda is necessary...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See __Notes__ here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct - basically it's unsafe and the lambda is the perfered safe option.

Comment: [See the extended answer to this question in this CppCon talk](https://youtu.be/9Tx97HeGnUQ?t=2157). Especially check the possible UB issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool foo(int i) { return true; }

int main() { 
    string str = string("");
    str.erase( std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), foo), str.end() );
    str.erase( std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ispunct), str.end() );
}
```

This contains a call using `foo`, and one with `std::ispunct`. The former is OK, and the latter is not.

The [error is](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dfced2af98fa2b8)

```
main.cpp:13:30: error: no matching function for call to 'remove_if(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   13 |     str.erase( std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ispunct), str.end() );)
```

```
main.cpp:13:30: error: no matching function for call to 'remove_if(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   13 |     str.erase( std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ispunct), str.end() );
```

So the problem is not with the conversion, since it works with `foo`. The problem is that it cannot resolve which overloading you mean. Note that there are actually two versions of [`ispunct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) (one is in [`<locale>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ispunct)).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which function is overloaded and the compiler can thus not resolve.
There's only [one declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) of `std::ispunct` function within `ctype`.
Within the header `algorithm` there's only one declaration of `remove_if` with three parameters, the third one being an unary predicate, which is resolved correctly as shown in your example with the function `foo`.

Comment: @bsng I get your confusion, because the second overload is in `<locale>` (modified the end of my answer to reflect that).

Comment: @AmiTavory Could you explain why this approach work: `using namespace std;` and then `s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::ispunct), s.end());`. In this approach, I had to put `::ispunct`, but neither `ispunct` nor `std::ispunct` would work. I don't understand what the difference is.